# How to avoid calling history.pushState in the popstate event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, html5-history

Let's say we have a `<p:commandLink action="…" onclick="history.pushState(…)">` that makes important changes to the state of the page. Primefaces 5.1 generates this HTML:

```xml
<a id="link1" href="#"
    onclick="history.pushState( {currentStateKeyWord: 'state1'},'','state1');
             PrimeFacesGeneratedFunction(stuff);">Click me for state 1</a>
<a id="link2" href="#"
    onclick="history.pushState( {currentStateKeyWord: 'state2'},'','state2');
             PrimeFacesGeneratedFunction(stuff);">Click me for state 2</a>
```

In the `popstate` event handler, we have to restore the state based on the object pushed as first parameter in `pushState`. Using JQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
        if ((event.originalEvent.state!==null)
             && (event.originalEvent.state.currentStateKeyWord!==undefined)) {
            switch (event.originalEvent.state.currentStateKeyWord) {
                case 'state1':
                    jQuery("#link1").click();
                    break;
                case 'state2':
                    jQuery("#link2").click();
                    break;
                 default:
                    console.error("Unknown state");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Why this doesn't work** : using `jQuery("#link1").click();` forces the link to work exactly as if the user clicked on it, which would be good, but unfortunately the `popstate` event handler must not call `history.pushState` (which is inside `onclick`). In Firefox this code breaks the forward button, which is undesirable.

**Question** : what would be the simplest way to correctly write the call to `history.pushState`, and the `popstate` event handler, taking into account that whatever we do, the `popstate` must trigger the call to `PrimeFacesGeneratedFunction(stuff)`?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you call `PrimeFacesGeneratedFunction()` directly in your `popstate` event handler instead of doing it indirectly ?

Comment: Because I don't know what the name of the generated function is, nor the parameters.

Comment: So in your `commandLink` tag, you specify `onclick` attribute with pushState, but when it's translated to HTML, PrimeFaces adds some additional js function to call in `onclick` in addition to what you mentioned in commandLink, is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. I solved the problem by using different JSF code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday I was thinking that the solution would be on the client-side, and as usual, I woke up this morning thinking completely differently.

My original JSF code was:

```xml
<p:commandLink action="#{associateBean.setState('state1')}" 
       onclick="history.pushState('{currentStateKeyWord: 'state1'}','','state1')"
       update="somePanel"/>

<p:commandLink action="#{associateBean.setState('state2')}" 
       onclick="history.pushState('{currentStateKeyWord: 'state2'}','','state2')"
       update="somePanel"/>
```

As described, the problem is that Primefaces generates an HTML anchor (`a`) and uses the `onclick` attribute to call my own `onclick` code (`history.pushState`) and some other function that is related to the content of the `action` attribute (`PrimefacesGeneratedFunction('stuff')`).

**Solution** is not to tweak the JavaScript, but to use `<p:remoteCommand>` to move the `action` content out of the `commandLink`.

New JSF code is:

```xml
<p:remoteCommand name="setState1"
     actionListener="#{associateBean.setState('state1')}"  
     update="somePanel"/>
<p:commandLink onclick="setState1();
     history.pushState('{currentStateKeyWord: 'state1'}','','state1')"/>

<p:remoteCommand name="setState2"
    actionListener="#{associateBean.setState('state2')}"
    update="somePanel"/>
<p:commandLink onclick="setState2();
    history.pushState('{currentStateKeyWord: 'state2'}','','state2')"/>
```

And now the `popstate` event handler references the `<p:remoteCommand name>` attribute instead of calling `click()` on the original link:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
        if ((event.originalEvent.state!==null)
             && (event.originalEvent.state.currentStateKeyWord!==undefined))     {
            switch (event.originalEvent.state.currentStateKeyWord) {
                case 'state1':
                    setState1();
                    break;
                case 'state2':
                    setState2();
                    break;
                 default:
                    console.error("Unknown state");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Cool.. Good to know this info :-)

Comment: I wonder if I could have a single `<p:remoteCommand>` tag and pass it some parameter, but that's another question. :)